# Was ist ein Oberboden, und wie unterscheidet sich das von einem Dachboden?

Tags: meaning

Derzeit lese ich Anne Franks *Tagebuch*. In der Beschreibung ihres Hinterhaus-Verstecks schreibt sie,

> Rechts und links sind Türen, die linke führt zum Vorderhaus mit den
> Lagerräumen, dem Dachboden und dem Oberboden.

"Dachboden" kann ich nachschlagen, und die Bedeutung ist ziemlich klar, aber ich finde keine sinnvolle Bedeutung für "Oberboden." Duden und andere Wörterbücher halten "Oberboden" als Synonym für "Mutterboden," d.h., die oberste Schicht der Erde. Das passt in diesem Zusammenhang gar nicht. DeepL und Google Translate erzeugen "upper floor" oder "top floor" als die englische Übersetzung, aber die wirken auch nicht richtig, weil die Türen im Zitat auf dem höchsten Stockwerk des Hauses sind. Kann jemand diese Sache erklären?

Comment: ["andere Wörterbücher"](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Oberboden) haben eine ganz klare Definition davon.

Comment: Naja, in dem DWDS-Eintrag steht unter "Bedeutung" etwas komplett anderes (Dachboden) als unter "Verwendungsbeispiele" gemeint sein kann (Mutterboden). Von daher nicht brauchbar bzw. bestätigt nur, dass diese Frage sinnvoll und hilfreich ist.

Comment: @Raketenolli du sagst also, der Eintrag unter "Bedeutung", der exakt die Frage klärt ist nicht hilfreich, weil bei den Verwendungsarten eine andere Bedeutung des Wortes steht, die im Kontext des obigen Textes so gar nicht passt?

Comment: Es könnte etwas gemeint sein, das man heute 'Spitzboden' nennt, siehe de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dachboden . Ansonsten kenne auch ich das Wort aus dem Gartenbau, wo es den dunkel gefärbten, mit Humus durchsetzten oberen Teil des Bodens bezeichnet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Das Folgende ist recht spekulativ, aber ich halte es für schlüssig genug, um daraus eine Antwort zu formulieren.

Mein erstes Bauchgefühl beim Begriff "Oberboden" war ein mehrteiliger oder mehrstöckiger Dachboden. Der "Oberboden" wäre dann der obere Teil davon.

In [einem Special zum Film "Meine Tochter Anne Frank"](https://static.hr.de/specials/anne-frank/indexca9a.html?rubrik=89963) beim Hessischen Rundfunk ist ein Aufriss des Hinterhauses, in dem sich Anne und ihre Familie versteckte, zu sehen. Zumindest das Hinterhaus hat laut diesem Aufriss tatsächlich einen mehrstöckigen Dachboden. Es könnte also gut sein, dass auch das Vorderhaus, von dem Anne in dem zitierten Abschnitt spricht, einen solchen mehrteiligen Dachboden hat, und sie den oberen Teil als "Oberboden" bezeichnet.

Ein allgemein gebräuchliches Wort ist heute meines Wissens jedenfalls nicht, oder nicht mehr.

Comment: Das ist tatsächlich so, und gibt es nur in alten Häusern mit relativ spitzen Dächern - einen mehrstöckigen Dachboden - und der obere davon ist eben der *Oberboden*.

Comment: Üblicherweise waren im "unteren" Dachboden in alten Stadthäusern die (kargen und meist unbeheizten) Dienstbotenzimmer untergebracht. Der Oberboden wurde so verwendet, wie wir uns heute einen Dachboden vorstellen: Für Krempel.

Comment: M. E. ist der "Dachboden und Oberboden" im **Vorderhaus** gemeint. Die bauliche Situation ist auf [diesem Foto](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Main_house_Anne_Frank_House_15.jpg) zu erkennen. Heutzutage sind die drei Häuser Prinsengracht 263, 265 und 267 mit Durchbrüchen miteinander verbunden. Ich glaube, hinten links geht man in die benachbarte Nr. 265. Wie man hinauf in den Oberboden gelangt, ist nicht zu erkennen. [Blick Richtung Hinterhaus](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Main_house_Anne_Frank_House_18.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Daß der Dachboden mehrgeschossig ist, liegt daran, daß Amsterdamer Bürgerhäuser bis in die Neuzeit - zumindest an den Grachten - nach der  *Breite ihrer Front* besteuert wurden. Deshalb sind die Häuser alle möglichst schmal und (deshalb) hoch gebaut. Oft genug waren die Treppen so eng, daß Möbel nicht durch die Stiegenhäuser transportiert werden konnten und deshalb außen am Haus hochgehievt werden mußten. Dafür (nämlich als Aufhängung eines Seilzuges) diente der an vielen dieser Häuser zu sehende Haken nahe des Dachgiebels und die Vorderfronten waren oft etwas gekragt, sodaß die Möbel, wenn sie mit dem Seilzug nach oben transportiert wurden, nicht mit der Fassade kollidierten.

Fun Fact: die Dienstboteneingänge wurden übrigens mit Absicht so niedrig gebaut, sodaß sich die Bediensteten beim Eintritt ins herrschaftliche Haus auch sicher bücken mußten.